# Configuration for Serilog.Sinks.MySQL when using appsettings.json file

Tags: mysql, serilog

I added Serilog to my app and the Console Sink works great. I then added the MySQL sink to the configuration. My settings are:

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.MySQL" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "Console" },
      {
        "Name": "MySQL",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "server=<server>;uid=<username>;pwd=<password>;database=logging_database",
          "tableName": "logging",
          "storeTimestampInUtc": true
        }
      }
    ],
}
```

I'm able to access the database with phpMyAdmin, so I know it's working.

The error that I get is:

```
Error: 0 : Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
```

Has anyone seen this or know how to fix it????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be with name resolution. The MySql server I was connecting to was being hosted on another server. I threw together a quick installation on a spare machine and just used IP address and it worked fine. So, on a hunch, I tried using the IP address instead of the name and it worked.

I also had to add SslMode=none into the connection string. I discovered that the sink doesn't gracefully handle connections that don't support SSL.